# Reporting Services Line Breaks When Exported Not In HTML

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

In Reportings Serivces 2005..I have a matrix control with a the below expression in one of the cells. The problem is that all these lines are running together when viewed from the report viewer. **It does, however, export in the correct format (pdf, excel).** This is a little issue but its drving me nuts. I use the same technique on other reports and they display as expected.

**Expression:**

```
=Fields!FullName.Value + " (" + Fields!Id.Value.ToString() + ") "
+ chr(10) + chr(13) 
+ "dob " + Format(Fields!DateOfBirth.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy")
+ chr(10) + chr(13) 
+ "Days Enrolled: " + Fields!OriginalDaysEnrolled.Value.ToString()
+ chr(10) + chr(13) 
+ "45 Day: " + Fields!ItemStringFor45Day.Value
+ chr(10) + chr(13) 
+ "90 Day: " + Fields!NinetyDay.Value.ToString()
+ chr(10) + chr(13) 
+ "Current: " + Fields!CurrentDescription.Value
+ chr(10) + chr(13) 
+ "Open Follow Ups: " + Fields!FollowUpCount.Value.ToString()
```

**Web Appearance (IE7, haven't checked others)**

> Doe, Johnny (123456) dob 03/30/2009 Days Enrolled: 98 45 Day: V H Deca Dev 90 Day: 18 Month Current: 18 Month Open Follow Ups: 1

**Exported Appearance (as expected and as Web should look)**

> Doe, Johnny (123456) 
>   
>   dob 03/30/2009 
>   
>   Days Enrolled: 98 
>   
>   45 Day: V H Deca Dev 
>   
>   90 Day: 18 Month 
>   
>   Current: 18 Month 
>   
>   Open Follow Ups: 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out after checking a report that was working correctly (for the fifth time)...it's simple.

**I used:**

```
+ chr(10) + chr(13)
```

**but I should have used:**

```
+ chr(13) + chr(10)
```

I feel silly for overlooking it for so long, but I guess it never popped out at me.

Answer (score 0):

White space is just white space to HTML; it condenses all the white space to a single space for presentation (including your `chr(10) + chr(13)`). In order for a line break, you either have to use a `<br />` tag or surround your line break values with `<pre></pre>`.

If you save the following as a ".html" file, you'll see that all characters will be displayed on the same line.

```
<html>
    <body>
        This is
        my          test
        for
        line breaks!
    </body>
</html>
```

However, this will yield the line breaks you want.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <pre>
            This is
            my          test
            for
            line breaks!
        </pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Easiest thing for you to do though is to replace your `chr(10) + chr(13)` with `<br />`. PDF and Excel will still respect the tag as a line break. If `<br />` doesn't work, try `&lt;br /&gt;` - I can't remember if Reporting Services encodes its output or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but thats the problem...In other reports I've done the "<br/>" was being generated by the report viewer, but not on this report. I figured it out, see my answer...thanks again.